# Multiple applications in task manager

Tags: java, android, taskmanager

a lot of times when I minimize my application I see two windows in task manager, example below:
[image]

Don't know if issue is related, but when I get only one application in task manager (as it should be) I don't see correct preview of it, it shows up as the top field in my example.
What could be the issue, anything specific I'm doing wrong and should look into?
Thank you for any help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.app.android"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="101"
android:versionName="1.01" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true" >
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="******************************"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsListener" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="5822">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPrefix=""
                    android:scheme="my.app.android" />
            <data
                    android:host="return"
                    android:pathPrefix=""
                    android:scheme="my.app.android" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".UserActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
    <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
    <activity android:name=".PaymentActivity"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

    <service android:name=".CheckService" />
</application>
```

Comment: Post you application Manifest.xml file , May be problem happen here..

Comment: As you have used `singleTask` mode, any reason why you have added `android:taskAffinity=""`? Can you remove it and see whether it solves the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activities are using different settings for taskAffinity.  Most of then use the default (no task affinity given), but one of them specifies the empty string as its taskAffinity.

Remove the line

```
   android:taskAffinity=""
```

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be the problem, I copied this from some boilerplate code and it had this property in it. Now I see correct preview, and only one application. I will award you bounty in 22h